# SQL Azure "The database XXX is not accessible"

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, azure-sql-database

I just created a user database using the SQL Azure portal.

I can manage my database with the portal, but I don't like it. It's not too Convenient so
I connected with my administrative user to my instance with the **Management Studio**. When I try to change the database from "master" to my user database i get the following error:

> SQL Azure "The database XXX is not accessible"

How can I overcome this problem ?

Thank you, Tal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that you well use Management Studio 2008R2
Do not forget to specify the db you want to manage in the Connection Options tab.

More info with screenshots on
http://debugmode.net/2010/12/13/connecting-from-sql-server-2008-management-studio-to-sql-azure/

Comment: Thanks ! 
I change the "Connect to database" property at the "Connect to Server" -> Options.

Answer (score 0):

Guidelines for connecting to SQL Azure database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336282.aspx